# Bootstrap 3 and Testing ASP.Net MVC project on IE8 in Windows 8.1

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I'm creating an ASP.Net MVC website and everything works great in all my browsers. The problem is, all of them are updated to the latest version. I used [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots) to test one of the demo pages I've published on my site just for testing purpose and saw that it works on most of the browsers except IE 7 & 8!!

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I've added both `html5shiv.js` and `respond.js` after my css links. They solved many problems but the screenshot is far from what I expect. So my questions are:

1. Is there another script that would somehow magically make the IE8 & 7 version like the new ones?
2. If not, I guess I have to create an IE8-specific stylesheet. Is there a tool that I can use to render the page in IE8 & 7 as I'm debugging the page (F5 in VS) and changing the CSS file and then refresh the page to see how it works? Considering I cannot just use a service like *BrowserStack* to test the page every time I just change one line of code.

Comment: Have you tested `normalize`?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi No I haven't but since the page doesn't work on older browsers, I don't think using `Normalize.css` would help. Also, Bootstrap already contains a `reset.LESS` file with this exact purpose.